# Use ids instead of full entities in JSON POST request with spring-boot application

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, post

I have created a spring-boot rest service which has post method

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<Order> createOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
```

Order entity looks like

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="destination")
    private Address destination;
    private String receiverLastName;
    private String receiverPhone;
    private float weight;
    private int height;
    private int length;
    private int width;
    private String description;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="courier")
    private User courier;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer")
    private User customer;
}
```

If I try to post this json:

```
{
    "destination":1,
    "receiverLastName": "Nieman",
    "receiverPhone": "+1145127789",
    "weight": 3.25,
    "height": 75,
    "length": 15,
    "width": 20,
    "description": "very fragile",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "courier":2,
    "customer":3
}
```

I get bad request error. Instead of "destination":1, for example, I need to use full entity. So, is it possible to use "flat" json with only ids instead of full entities with whole set of field?

Comment: If you means something like `destination:{"id": 1}` it is possible.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely what I wanted to use. Thank you!